# Force Excel to save files with .TSV file extension

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv

I am using Microsoft Excel to work with tab delimited files. Although I can import tsv files without an issue, I can't save them with the TSV extension. Instead, I have to

```
1. Import the TSV file into Excel
2. Make my changes
3. Save the changed file as .txt
4. Delete the original .tsv file
5. Rename the .txt file as .tsv
```

Is there a way to force Excel to save as .tsv file directly?

I am using Excel 16.16 running on Mac OS El Capitan 10.11.6

EDIT: While I was unable to use "Save as" to save as a TSV file, using the default save function keeps the TSV extension.

Comment: As already answered, Excel can't do that.  You may use a macro to save your file, delete previous version, than rename it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot using the default capabilities of Excel.

The "correct" method for Excel is to save as a Tab Separated Value (.txt) and then rename the extension, which appears to be what you're currently doing.